# Does GlusterFS works only in the same subnet?

Tags: glusterfs

I would like to know if GlusterFS is working only in the same subnet ?

How can I make it works if it can ?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Quick answer: It does work in different subnets!

Initially I ask this question because it wasn't working.

After some try I find my port 24000 wasn't reachable.
My OVH vps wasn't working well..

I reinstalled it and now it's working great.